# How do I see items that I already passed in a review queue?

Tags: support, reviewing

After passing through a review queue in Arqade, I would like to revisit some of these questions/answers, but don't remember the name or any of the text in that question.

I do not want to have to manually search it up. What do I do?

**EDIT:** According to [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15124/250180), there is supposed to be a second paragraph letting you see your history. However this paragraph is not there. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

Are they review items you completed or skipped?

If it's the former, go to your profile, select "All Actions" then "Reviews".

If it's the latter, things are a bit more difficult, and *someone* has had to perform a review action.  Go to the review queue, then select "History".  You can also filter to just your own reviews from there as well.

If you're still in the review queue, you can also hit the back button to see how others reviewed a particular item after you've completed your review.

Comment: There's no back button on the page...

Comment: in your browser (sorry I wasn't clear about that)

Comment: I think you only see full review history at 10k, before that it just shows your own reviews

Answer (score 2):

If you have at least 10k rep, once you've completed reviewing all items in a queue, or you go to a review queue with no reviews in it, you will be presented with this page.[image]

If you have less than 10k rep, you can also use the history portion of the the queue to view your previous reviews, and clicking the checkbox will allow you to view skipped reviews.
[image]

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer! I actually don't see that second paragraph, only the first. Is there a reason why this might be happening?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 that’s weird. Let me see if I can check on a different site that I don’t have as much rep or mod privileges on to see if I can replicate the issue

Comment: Hmm, it seems it may be tied to the 10k rep privilege unlocks https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools , though i feel like you should be able to see that link for your own reviews regardless, though it doesnt seem possible at present. ill ping some people about it to confirm

Comment: I also don't see that link.

Comment: The link/second paragraph doesn't show up in the empty review page (that might be a moderator thing?) but if you go to the History tab it looks the same including the "show skipped reviews" option.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot if you read the second paragraph it says that it is on the history section/tab. I took that screenshot on a site where I am not a mod.

Comment: Maybe it's an SO-only thing (I believe that's where you took the screenshot)? Or part of the review improvement project thing they're working on. I don't see it on either SFF (>10k) or here (<10k). In fact I don't see the second paragraph on SO either. Got a userscript running?